# Facebook App Configuration Requires App Review?

Tags: facebook-login

I have five different Facebook apps to support Facebook Login in my ASP.NET Core web application. The four apps support our dev, integration, QA, staging and production environments.

I recently received an email stating that these apps need to be reviewed by August 1st because they configured to receive more than just email and public_profile content. (Some of my apps also are configured to receive user_friends, which I don't want or need.) I'm not finding a way to change the configuration of my app to only request the user and public_profile permissions.

Any help on removing the user_friends permission from my apps would be super helpful.

Thanks!

-Brian Eriksen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question, my app was only created to embed a Like button, and does not require any permissions.

The notification I'm seeing says:

> If your app does not require the use of these permissions and features, no review is required, and no further action needs to be taken on your part.

So if you're sure you're not using the permission, just dismiss/ignore the notification. Presumably the 'user_friends' permission will be automatically removed from the app after the deadline passes.

Comment: Facebook sent an additional email notification that stated more clearly that if you don't use the permissions (like user_friends) then doing nothing is fine. Their first email notification was not clear!